# How does encapsulation works in OOP

Tags: java, c#, oop, encapsulation

```
public interface IShoulders {
    public void move();
}

public class Body {

public void createBody(){
    RightHand rightHand = new RightHand();
    rightHand.move();
    IShoulders leftHand = new LeftHand();
    leftHand.move();
}

}

public class RightHand implements IShoulders {

    public void move(){
        System.out.println("Move Right Hand");          
    }   
}

public class LeftHand implements IShoulders {

public void move(){
    System.out.println("Move Left Hand");           
}   
}
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Body myBody1 = new Body();
    myBody1.createBody();


    Body myBody2 = new Body();
    myBody2.createBody();
}

}
```

Please explain in the class `body` how is the encapsulation different when `IShoulder leftHand = new LeftHand();` is used in comparison with `RightHand rightHand = new RightHand();` they are both doing the same thing so when to use what and why is it important ? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it comes down to is that when accessing a field, you access it as it is immediately typed. In this case, when you have a field typed as an interface: `IShoulders`, you can only directly access any properties/methods defined by the interface. When you access a field defined as a class that implements that same interface, this new field, defined and accessed as `RightHand`, provides access to not only those properties/methods defined by `IShoulders` but also and extended properties/methods defined by the class `RightHand`.

With your definitions, there is no real difference here aside from the value that `move()` prints out, but take the following changes:

```
public class RightHand implements IShoulders {

    public void move(){
        System.out.println("Move Right Hand");          
    }
    public void Gesture()
    {
        System.out.println("Make a gesture with Right Hand");
    }   
}
```

The new `Gesture` method is only accessible to a field defined as `RightHand`, it will not exist on a field that is defined only has `IShoulders`, even if you assign the field using a `new RightHand()`, you would need to box or convert the field to `RightHand` to access the new method.

Given the above `RightHand` class definition, try the following:

```
IShoulders shoulder = new RightHand();
shoulder.move(); // this will work fine...
shoulder.Gesture(); // this will not be possible as "Gesture()" does not exist on IShoulders.
((RightHand)shoulder).Gesture(); // this will work after casting shoulder as RightHand
                                 // since the underlying object is actually a RightHand.
```

Then try the following:

```
RightHand rhand = new RightHand();
rhand.move(); // again, this works fine...
rhand.Gesture(); // this now works fine too..
```

Further more, the interface is your contract for any class that implements it. It simply says that if a class implements an interface, it must implement everything in that interface. It says nothing, however, about HOW it should be implemented. So, as long as the class implements the structure of the interface, the contents of those implementations can be completely customized to each individual class.

The alternative to implementing an interface is creating a derived class using a sub-class. This can seem similar to implementing an interface, however the base class already has implementations of the properties and methods. They can be overridden unless you either do not decorate them with `virtual` or, at another level of inheritance, you override and use the `final` decoration.

> I;m sorry but lets tone this down as its still a little confusing.
>   When i write IShoulder rightHand or RightHand rightHand i;m defining
>   the type of the object before creating it? Also i always wanted to ask
>   why we need to define a type if we are using the new keyword anyway
>   like we do with any other objects like of collections? list<> mylist =
>   new list<> and how to address this verbally? like object rightHand of
>   class RightHand encapsulate RightHand/IShoulder? correct me if iam
>   wrong – eersteam

Sure, so as for typing variables - this allows for the compiler (and programmer, for that matter) to strongly define what can be used, and how it can be used in regards to an object/value. A simple example would be a function:

```
public string HyphenateTwoWords(string word1, string word2)
{
   return string.Format("{0}-{1}", word1, word2);
}
```

The above function takes two `string` parameters and joins them together with a hyphen between them. If the parameters were not typed as `string`, then anything could be passed in and the result could be simply wrong in some cases, or throw an exception in other cases. Since they are defined as `string` the `string.Format()` call executes without any issues.

Now, in C# and other languages, you can actually define a field/variable generically using `var`, for example:

```
List<string> myStringList = new List<string>();
myStringList.Add("Test1");
myStringList.Add("Test2");
myStringList.Add("Test3");
foreach(var item in myStringList)
   Console.WriteLine(item);
```

This lets the compiler infer what the actual type of `item` is based upon what is assigned to it. However, in most cases, you would not really want to use `var`. It is best to explicitly type your variables, if for no other reasons, readability. It is a lot easier to see what the type of a variable is, especially when you are working in code maintained by multiple developers. Plus, explicitly typing a variable ensures that is will be used as intended, otherwise a handlable exception is thrown or the compiler will throw an error or warning upon build of the solution.

Now, in regards to your comment above:

> ...how would i know if its left hand or right hand?
>   and in my example hands are not shoulders but hands are suppose to be
>   attached to the should because shoulder makes them capable of moving.
>   So how would you implement this? – eersteam

Let's design some interfaces and classes to illustrate their uses, I will make some changes/additions to what you have already all of these should be fairly straight forward- Take a look at `AddLegs()` method on the `Body` class and look at the `LeftLeg` class too.

```cs
public class BodyConstructor
{
    public interface IBody
    {
        int Age { get; set; }
        string Species { get; set; }
        BodyPartGroup Head { get; set; }
        BodyPartGroup Thorax { get; set; }
        BodyPartGroup Abdomen { get; set; }
        BodyPartGroup Pelvis { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IBodyPartGroup
    {
        BodyPartGroupType Type { get; set; }
        List<IBodyPart> BodyParts { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IBodyPart
    {
        LateralDirection LateralOrientation { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
        List<IBodyPart> SubParts { get; set; }
        void Move();
    }

    public enum BodyPartGroupType
    {
        Head = 1,
        Thorax = 2,
        Abdomen = 3,
        Pelvis = 4,
    }

    public enum LateralDirection
    {
        Central = 0,
        Right = 1,
        Left = 2,
    }



    public class Body : IBody
    {
        public Body()
        {
            Head = new BodyPartGroup(BodyPartGroupType.Head);
            Thorax = new BodyPartGroup(BodyPartGroupType.Thorax);
            Abdomen = new BodyPartGroup(BodyPartGroupType.Abdomen);
            Pelvis = new BodyPartGroup(BodyPartGroupType.Pelvis);
        }
        public Body(int age, string species)
            : this()
        {
            Age = age;
            Species = species;
        }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Species { get; set; }
        public BodyPartGroup Head { get; set; }
        public BodyPartGroup Thorax { get; set; }
        public BodyPartGroup Abdomen { get; set; }
        public BodyPartGroup Pelvis { get; set; }

        public void AddLimbs()
        {
            AddArms();
            AddLegs();
        }

        public void AddArms()
        {
            // Individual segments for the left arm
            BodyPart leftShoulder = new BodyPart("Left Shoulder", LateralDirection.Left);
            BodyPart leftArm = new BodyPart("Left Arm", LateralDirection.Left);
            BodyPart leftHand = new BodyPart("Left Hand", LateralDirection.Left);
            leftArm.SubParts.Add(leftHand);
            leftShoulder.SubParts.Add(leftArm);
            // Individual segments for the right arm
            BodyPart rightShoulder = new BodyPart("Right Shoulder", LateralDirection.Right);
            BodyPart rightArm = new BodyPart("Right Arm", LateralDirection.Right);
            BodyPart rightHand = new BodyPart("Right Hand", LateralDirection.Right);
            rightArm.SubParts.Add(rightHand);
            rightShoulder.SubParts.Add(rightArm);

            // Add arms to thorax
            Thorax.BodyParts.Add(rightShoulder);
            Thorax.BodyParts.Add(leftShoulder);

        }

        public void AddLegs()
        {
            // Individual segments for the left leg
            BodyPart leftHip = new BodyPart("Left Hip", LateralDirection.Left);
            LeftLeg leftLeg = new LeftLeg(); // Here we use the LeftLeg class instead, which inherits BodyPart
            BodyPart leftFoot = new BodyPart("Left Foot", LateralDirection.Left);
            leftLeg.SubParts.Add(leftFoot);
            leftHip.SubParts.Add(leftLeg);

            //Individual segments for the right leg
            BodyPart rightHip = new BodyPart("Right Hip", LateralDirection.Right);
            BodyPart rightLeg = new BodyPart("Right Leg", LateralDirection.Right);
            BodyPart rightFoot = new BodyPart("Right Foot", LateralDirection.Right);
            rightLeg.SubParts.Add(rightFoot);
            rightHip.SubParts.Add(rightLeg);

            // Add legs to pelvis
            Pelvis.BodyParts.Add(leftHip);
            Pelvis.BodyParts.Add(rightHip);
        }
    }

    public class BodyPartGroup : IBodyPartGroup
    {
        public BodyPartGroup()
        {
            BodyParts = new List<IBodyPart>();
        }
        public BodyPartGroup(BodyPartGroupType type)
            : this()
        {
            this.Type = type;
        }
        public BodyPartGroupType Type { get; set; }
        public List<IBodyPart> BodyParts { get; set; }
    }

    public class BodyPart : IBodyPart
    {
        public BodyPart()
        {
            SubParts = new List<IBodyPart>();
        }
        public BodyPart(string name, LateralDirection orientation)
            : this()
        {
            Name = name;
            LateralOrientation = orientation;
        }
        // Location of body part: Left, Central, Right
        public LateralDirection LateralOrientation { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<IBodyPart> SubParts { get; set; }
        public virtual void Move()
        {
            // Common body part movement code.
        }
    }

    public class LeftLeg : BodyPart
    {
        public LeftLeg()
        {
            Name = "Left Leg";
            LateralOrientation = LateralDirection.Left;
        }
        public override void Move()
        {
            // Custom left leg move code

            base.Move(); // Call base BodyPart.Move();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I;m sorry but lets tone this down as its still a little confusing. When i write IShoulder rightHand or RightHand rightHand i;m defining the type of the object before creating it? Also i always wanted to ask why we need to define a type if we are using the new keyword anyway like we do with any other objects like of collections? list<> mylist = new list<> and how to address this verbally? like object rightHand of class RightHand encapsulate RightHand/IShoulder? correct me if iam wrong

Comment: I have updated my answer with some more information about typing fields/variables. I'll try to give you some explanations, however, this is really a very broad subject which may be better for you to read about in a book or tutorial on general OOP conventions and practices.

Comment: I disagree vociferously with regards to "var". There are instances where it could hide your type, but in the majority of instances where the type is declared to the right of the assignment statement using var improves readability and maintainability.

Comment: If you are declaring a `new` there, sure, but `foreach(var item in myobject.GetCollection()) { /* .. */ }` gives no clue. You can disagree all you want, but I was just making a statement on a general opinion about readability, to someone who appears to be a beginner in this subject. The point about explicitly typing variables to ensure proper use and assignment is also still very valid.

Comment: Thank you gimley for your in depth answer   waiting for your implementation of the example  also please mention who is encapsulating what / who is being encapsulated by what    when you define and access an object    (which is what i wanted to learn originally)

Comment: Sorry, some stuff came up and I had to go out for a bit, but I have updated my answer a bit more for you with some example code using interfaces and classes.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, leftHand is a LeftHand and rightHand is a RightHand. Both *objects* you created are instances of classes that implement IShoulder. Both ARE IShoulders and therefore can "move". The difference between the leftHand and rightHand *variables* is that you can set leftHand to the instance of the RightHand class, because leftHand was declared as IShoulder, which could be either. If you did that, and then called leftHand.move(), it would move the right hand. Get it?

What the interface gets you is the ability to work with either hand not needing to know which hand you're actually working with. In your example, If you named the IShoulder interface IHand and then named the IHand variable hand instead of leftHand, it would make a lot more sense. Your example implies that hands are shoulders.

But that's not what encapsulation is about. Encapsulation is simply putting together related data and the methods that act on that data, and restricting outside access to only the components that contribute to its essential characteristics (i.e. hide the details). So a Body class might encapsulate the head, arms, legs, torso, etc. And an arm might encapsulate a shoulder, upper arm, elbow, lower arm and hand. All you see from the outside looking in is an arm with parts that can do things you would expect an arm to do. You're expected to use the Arm class without knowing or caring how it does its job. Here's an example:

```
// the arm class encapsulates the parts of the arm (the data), and the behavior of the arm (the methods).
class Arm
{    
    Shoulder shoulder = new Shoulder();
    Hand hand = new Hand();
    UpperArm upperArm = new UpperArm();
    Elbow elbow = new Elbow();
    LowerArm lowerArm = new LowerArm();

    void poke()
    {         
        flinch();
    }

    void flinch()
    {
        // write some code that flinches the arm
    }

    void move()
    {
         // move the arm all over the place 
         shoulder.move();
         hand.wave(); 
         doHighFive();
         //...  
    }

    void doHighFive()
    {
         // move all the arm parts in a high-five motion
    }
}



// the Body class encapsulates the parts of the body (the data), and the behavior of the body (the methods).
class Body
{    
    Head head = new Head();
    Torso torso = new Torso();
    Arm leftArm = new Arm();
    Arm rightArm = new Arm();
    Leg leftLeg = new Leg();
    Leg rightLeg = new Leg();

    void poke()
    {         
        flinch(); 
        dance();
        System.out.println("I didn't flinch, I was just dancing! Now I'm tired, though."); 
        goToBed();
    }

    void flinch()
    {
        // write some code that makes the body flinch
    }

    void dance()
    {
         // write code to make the body dance
    }

    void goToBed()
    {
         // write code to make the body go to bed
    }
}
```

Your question, though, seems to be more about when to use an interface rather than one of the classes that implements that interface. This is more a question about abstract data types, not encapsulation. An abstract data type is defined by its behavior only (no code or data). An interface is a way to define an abstract data type. It's just a list of method signatures; think of it like a contract for how implementers must behave.

So when would you use an interface? Well as an example, if my job is to iterate through a collection of body parts and "poke" them, I don't really care what specific types of body parts you give me, I just need to poke them. Here's an example:

```
// IBodyPart defines an abstract data type that can be "poked", among other things.
interface IBodyPart
{
    void poke();
    //...
}

// maybe hands handle being poked by slapping
class Hand implements IBodyPart
{
    void poke()
    {         
        slap();
    }

    void slap()
    {
        // write some code that slaps
    }
}

// maybe shoulders just flinch
class Shoulder implements IBodyPart
{
    void poke()
    {         
        flinch();
    }

    void flinch()
    {
        // write some code to flinch the shoulder
    }
}

// etc. Each IBodyPart class has to implement the poke method.

// I don't know nor do I care what I'm poking. I can do my job easily thanks to abstract data types!
class Me
{
    void PokeEmAll(List<IBodyPart> bodyPartList)
    {
        for (IBodyPart bodyPart : bodyPartList)
        {
            bodyPart.poke();
        }
    }
}

class Main
{
    // create a list of body parts so I can poke 'em all
    static void main()
    {
        List<IBodyPart> bodyPartList = new List<IBodyPart>();
        Hand leftHand = new Hand();
        bodyPartList.add(leftHand);
        Hand rightHand = new Hand();
        bodyPartList.add(rightHand);
        Shoulder leftShoulder = new Shoulder();
        bodyPartList.add(leftShoulder);
        Shoulder rightShoulder = new Shoulder();
        bodyPartList.add(rightShoulder);  

        Me me = new Me();
        me.PokeEmAll(bodyPartList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks okay but then how would i know if its left hand or right hand? and in my example hands are not shoulders but hands are suppose to be attached to the should because shoulder makes them capable of moving. So how would you implement this?

Comment: In that case you would want an object called `Shoulder` that implements `IShoulders`, and `IShoulders` interface should have a property added to it called `Arm` typed as a new interface of `IArm`. I will update my answer with an extended example.

Comment: @eersteam, you wouldn't be using the interface if you cared whether you were working with a left hand or a right hand. I think your question is more coming out of a lack of knowledge of what an interface is for, than it is about encapsulation. See my updates to my answer where I tried to address that. How would I implement this? I would encapsulate both hands and shoulders in the body class with all the other body parts. The body (not the shoulders) would be responsible for moving the hands in conjunction with moving the shoulders, if the desired hand movement makes that necessary.